# Angular modal popup doesn't reposition when clicked on another element

Tags: angular, scroll, modal-dialog

I have about 100 table elements. When I click to edit on the element #100 the modal popup appears next to it on the bottom of the page. When I scroll back and click on the element #1 the popup is still on the bottom and not visible. What an I do to make the popup float back when I scroll up or appear on top next to an element when I click?

```
SCSS:

@import "~app/design-library/scss/colors.scss";
@import "~app/design-library/scss/layout.scss";

@mixin modalSection {
  padding: 1rem;
}

:host {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2000;

  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;

  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, as simple as changing to

```
  position: fixed;
```

Now the back is scrolling and the modal is always on the center.